# Deploy Silverlight web site with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, silverlight-5.0, service-reference

I have Silverlight web site which i want to deploy it with Azure Devops. before deploying I should change service addresses on ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file. Actually I could change web.config connection string with Variable transform but it dose not work for ServiceReferences.ClientConfig.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Replace Tokens` task:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/*.config
      **/*.json => outputs/*.json
```